# Making a matrix symmetric, in-place vs. out-of-place

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a matrix which is supposed to be symmetric (it's the inverse of symmetric), but it is not exactly due to numerical errors in the inversion etc.

So, I add a step of making the matrix symmetric (by `a = .5(a+a'`), and I see a numerical disaster if I do it in-place (out-of-place is ok). Code:

```
import numpy as np

def check_sym(x):
    print("||a-a'||^2 = %e" % np.sum((x - x.T)**2))

# make a symmetric matrix
dim = 100
a = np.random.randn(dim,dim)
a = np.matmul(a, a.T)
b = a.copy()

check_sym(a)

print("symmetrizing in-place")
a += a.T
a *= .5
check_sym(a)

print("symmetrizing out-of-place")
b = .5 * (b + b.T)
check_sym(b)
```

And the output is:

```
||a-a'||^2 = 1.184044e-26
symmetrizing in-place
||a-a'||^2 = 7.313593e+04
symmetrizing out-of-place
||a-a'||^2 = 0.000000e+00
```

Note that for lower dimension (e.g. `dim=10`) the problem does not appear.

**EDIT** some more info is given by looking at `a-a'` after the in-place version:
[image: a minus a.transpose]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error comes from the line `a += a.T`. It is a known problem of the in-place operations (I cannot find right now the proper piece of documentation that states so) but quoted from [scipy lecture notes](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/intro/numpy/operations.html):

> The transposition is a view.
>
> As a results, the following code is wrong and will not make a matrix symmetric:
>
> ```
> a += a.T
> ```
>
> It will work for small arrays (because of buffering) but fail for large one, in unpredictable ways.

The reason is that at the same time `a` is being updated with `a.T`, `a.T` is actually changing (since it is a *memoryview* of `a`), and thus updating some coordinates of `a` incorrectly.

If you want to symmetrize a matrix in-place, you could do the following:

```
a = np.random.rand(4,4)
a[np.tril_indices_from(a)] = a.T[np.tril_indices_from(a)]
```

Or, if you want to stick to your notation:

```
a += a.T.copy()
```

since `copy` will create a temporary copy of `a.T` which is not going to be updated.

Comment: Wow. I find it surprising that such a behavior is possible, since doing `a+=a.T` seems a reasonable thing to do (in any language, not only Python). Couldn't the code be designed to raise an exception in such a case?